# For each pair of points in an open connected set, is there a connected open precompact subset that contains both points?

Tags: general-topology

Let $U$ be an open connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $x,y \in U$. Does there exist a connected open and precompact subset $V$ of $U$ such that $x,y \in V$?

My thoughts so far: If $U$ is path connected then there exists a path $\phi:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$ from $x$ to $y$. Then we could take $V$ to be a "tube" around $\phi([0,1])$ that is sufficiently "narrow" that it's contained in $U$. The problem, as I have just discovered, is that $U$ being connected does not that $U$ is path-connected, so this idea doesn't work...Without asumming path-connectedness I'm pretty stumped. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a path $p:[0, 1]\to U$ such that $p(0) = x$ and $p(1) = y$. This is possible since open connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is path-connected. To see this, for example, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally path-connected, hence $U$ has open path-connected components (a space is locally path-connected iff every open subset has open path-components), this of course means it has to be path-connected itself.

Note that $r = d(\text{im}(p), U^c) > 0$ (without loss of generality assume $U^c$ is non-empty) since $\text{im}(p)$ is compact.

Let $V = B(\text{im}(p), r/2) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n : d(\text{im}(p), x) < r/2\}$. Then $V\subseteq U$ is open, connected and precompact, with $\overline{V}\subseteq U$.

Comment: @Thanks a lot for your answer! I did not know that open connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are path connected, so that's good to know. One question: What's the easiest way of seeing that your choice of $V$ is connected?

Comment: @Leonidas Its a union of sets $\text{img}(p)\cup B(x, r/2)$ for $x\in\text{img}(p)$ which are connected, and have non-empty intersection (since it contains $\text{im}(p)$). Union of connected sets with non-empty intersection is connected